# unable to load database value in php in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am entry level developer in PHP and have no knowledge in PHP, i am trying to call database values on selecting a drop down menu, have done this so far with the help of tutorial,.. the problem is when i select 1st drop down the second drop down is getting values from DB, but when i select option from 2nd drop down menu, i am not getting any data displayed on page. Nothing Happens after selecting an option from 2nd drop down.

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
 $unm=htmlentities($_SESSION['username']);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> User Panel</title></head>

<body background="../image/pencilback.jpg">
<div id="welcome"><?php
echo '<align="right">'.'<h3>'."Welcome ".$unm.'</h3>';
?></div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/heading.css">
<table border="0" width="50%" height="150px" align="center" >
<tr width="100%" height="200px" > <td colspan="3"> <img src="../image/banner.jpg"> </td>  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tableborder" border="0" width="83%" height="40px" align="center" bgcolor="#BDBDBD" >

<td align="center"><a href="userpanel.php"><b> Take a Test</b></a> </td> 
<td align="center"><a href="myaccount.php"><b> My Account Details</b> </td>
<td align="center"><a href="testhistory.php"><b> View Test History </b> </td> 
<td align="center"><a href="feedback.php"><b> Give Feedback</b> </td>
<td align="center"><a href="../logout.php"><b> Logout</b> </td> </td>  </tr>
</table>
<form method="POST" action="">
 <div id="viewset"><center>
  Select Desired Test </center> <br></div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <table border="1px" align="center" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="10px">
 <tr> <td> <select name="tstcat" id="countrydd" onChange="change_country()">
<option> Select Test Category</option>
<?php
$res=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from sub");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["subname"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["subname"]; ?> </option>
<?php
    }
?>

</select>
</td>
<td>
 <div id="state" align="center">
<select id="details" onChange="display_details()">
<option>Select Test</option>
</select>

</div>
 </tr> </td></table>
<br>

<div id="display">
<table border="1px" height="100px" width="30%" align="center">
<tr style=color:maroon> <th> Test Name </th> <th> No. of Questions </th> <th> Duration </th> </tr>
<tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr>
</table>

</div>

<center> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></center>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$tstct=$_POST['tstcat'];
$tnm=$_POST['testid'];
$_SESSION['testname']=$tnm;
$_SESSION['testcatg']=$tsc;
header('location:teststart.php');
}
?>

 </div>
 </form>



 <script type="text/javascript">

 //========== FOR DROPDOWN SELECTION

 function change_country()
 {
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?category="+document.getElementById("countrydd").value,false);
     xmlhttp.send(null);
     document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

 }

  //========== TO LOAD TEST DETAILS

 function display_details()
 {
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax2.php?testname="+document.getElementById("details").value,false);
     xmlhttp.send(null);
     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

 }

 </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

***AJAX.PHP***

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
$category=$_GET["category"];

if($category!="")
{
$res=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from test_detail where     test_category='$category'");
echo "<select name='testid' onchange='change_test()'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["test_name"];?>"> <?php echo $row["test_name"];?>  </option>
    <?php
}
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

***AJAX 2.PHP***

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
$tstname=$_GET["testname"];

if($tstname!="")
{
$res1=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from test_detail where  test_name='$tstname'");
echo "<table>";
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
{
    ?>

    <tr> <td> <?php echo $row1["test_name"];?>  </td> 
    <td> <?php echo $row1["total_ques"];?> </td> 
    <td> <?php echo $row1["test_dur"];?> </td> </tr>
    <?php
}
echo "</table>";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: you should be changing `details` to I think `testid` when pulling the data for the second dropdown, you're referring to an empty select options, and from your ajax.php you're loading options with a `testid` id for select. not really sure what you're doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to check three things.

1. in the select that is inside to the div with id #state, you have an onChange calling the javascript function 'display_details()' which you use to load the table element with detail data. But when you return the select from AJAX.PHP the onchange event has another function 'change_test()', it should be 'display_details()'
2. When you insert dynamically new html elements in a document, normally you have to use dynamic event binding to attach the event handlers. For this I recommend you to use jquery, this link explain how [Event binding on dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)
3. to make to ajax request jquery is very good library, but if you want to use the XMLHttpRequest object , It will be a good idea check the status of the response:

   if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
       document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }else{
        // Handle the error;
   }

Comment: Thank you for replying, i will try this out today and reply. :)

Comment: Thank You, It worked... I just changed   in ajax2.php -- <table name='tstnm'>